# Wipe data on android tablet without using touch screen

Tags: android

I want to wipe out data on an Android tablet that has a broken touch screen. Basically, I want to clean out everything before I dispose of the tablet. The tablet is ASUS MemoPad ME302C, and it is running Android 4.3.

Things I've tried so far.

A triangular area along the edge, about a quarter of the whole touch screen is still functioning. I tried to maneuver my way to the factory reset screen, but couldn't press the confirmation button.

I wanted to use adb command line tool to do factory reset. But the documentation says that I need to enable USB debugging on the tablet first. I managed to bring up the hidden "developer" menu item, but couldn't press the confirm button to enable USB debugging.

Comment: Does you tablet have an HDMI or MHL out?

Comment: @Mahdi I’m not sure why the output is relevant; it seems like thebat can see everything just fine, but the screen won’t respond to all the touches.

Comment: My bad, i thought the whole screen has broken. Then Icd sugggest an OTG cable and a wireless mouse or a Bluetooth mouse if the OP can navigate the pair process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I don’t have your specific model of tablet available; this is what I gathered from the Internet based on knowing how to do it with my devices. I think it will work, but I’m not certain.

You can wipe your device from recovery mode, without using a touch screen.

***To get into the recovery menu:***

1. With the device off, hold the power and volume up buttons down for a few seconds (note: The procedure to get into recovery is different for different devices; this is the correct answer for the Asus MemoPad. See the “For other devices” section if this doesn’t work for you). You are now in recovery mode.
2. Press the power and volume up buttons simultaneously again. You should now see an on-screen menu.

***To actually wipe data from recovery:***

1. Use the volume up and down keys to scroll to the “wipe data/factory reset” option in the recovery menu. Click the power button to select it.
2. You get a confirmation screen, with a bunch of “no” options and one “yes” option. Use the volume keys to highlight the “yes” option, and the power button to activate it.
3. Repeat the previous steps with “wipe cache partition”.

***For other devices:***

You might not be able to enter recovery mode using the above method. Instead, try to enter it via the bootloader:

1. With the device turned off, hold the power and volume *down* buttons for a few seconds. You should now be in the bootloader. There should be large print somewhere (possibly in an arrow pointing to the power button) saying “start”.
2. Hitting the volume up or volume down buttons will select options other than “start”. Once you see the recovery mode option, hit the power button to select it.
3. Wait a bit. You are now in recovery mode, but do not have a menu. Proceed with step 2 of the “To get into the recovery menu” section to get the menu.

Comment: Cool! I was able to do a factory reset through the recovery mode.

Answer (score -1):

If you really just want to dispose it, then a hammer may come very handy in destroying the data. Take some pictures along the way as you open in up, and hammer those memory chips.

If you happen to have a USB mouse around and an OTG cable *or* a Bluetooth mouse and you can navigate the pairing process with shat remains working, then you can basically have a touch alternative and you will be in business.

I still like the other answer regarding factory reset from off state better though, no touch screen needed.